# Tetrachords lines in Musixtex

Tags: tikz-pgf, musixtex

It is needed to add bottom lines that represent semitones and tones for tetrachords, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 


\begin{document}
(b) Minor pentachord

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \setclef1{\bass}
    \parindent3pt
    \startextract
    \Notes\wh{^F^GHI^JKL^MLK^JIH^G^F}\en
    \zendextract
 \end{music}
 
(c) Natural minor 

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \setclef1{\bass}
    \nostartrule
    \nobarnumbers
    \startextract
    \Notes\wh{^F^GHI^JKL^MLK^JIH^G^F}\en
    \zendextract
 \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The expected output should be:
[image: expected]

Comment: Did you try anything yourself with tikz? In none of your questions you tell what you tried yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=22mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}    
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\begin{document}
(b) Minor pentachord

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {
\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \setclef1{\bass}
    \parindent3pt
    \startextract
    \Notes\wh{^F^GHI^JKL^MLK^JIH^G^F}\en
    \zendextract
 \end{music}
 };
 \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    %Código para grillas
    %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
    %\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
    %\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    %Dibujando lineas y texto
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.173,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.05,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.227,0.1) -- ++(0.025,-0.07)-- ++(0.025,0.07);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.28,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.05,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.334,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.05,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.172,0.75) -- ++(0,0.05)-- ++(0.205,0)-- ++(0,-0.05);
    \node[text width=3.5cm,align=center] (minorPentaChord1) at (0.275,0.88) {\footnotesize minor pentachord};
             
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.68,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.05,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.735,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.05,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.79,0.1) -- ++(0.025,-0.07)-- ++(0.025,0.07);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.843,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.05,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.68,0.75) -- ++(0,0.05)-- ++(0.205,0)-- ++(0,-0.05);
    \node[text width=3.5cm,align=center] (minorPentaChord2) at (0.78,0.88) {\footnotesize minor pentachord};
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}

(c) Natural minor 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {    
\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \setclef1{\bass}
    \nostartrule
    \nobarnumbers
    \startextract
    \NOtes\wh{^F^GHI^JKL^MLK^JIH^G^F}\en
    \zendextract
 \end{music}
 };
 \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    %Código para grillas
    %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
    %\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
    %\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    %Dibujando lineas y texto
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.365,0.1) -- ++(0.025,-0.07)-- ++(0.025,0.07);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.417,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.048,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.468,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.048,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.519,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.048,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.57,0.1) -- ++(0,-0.05)-- ++(0.048,0)-- ++(0,0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.62,0.1) -- ++(0.025,-0.07)-- ++(0.025,0.07);
    
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.365,0.75) -- ++(0,0.05)-- ++(0.149,0)-- ++(0,-0.05);
    \draw[line width=1pt,red] (0.518,0.75) -- ++(0,0.05)-- ++(0.149,0)-- ++(0,-0.05);
    \node[text width=4.5cm,align=center] (minorPentaChord1) at (0.525,0.88) {\footnotesize natural minor tetrachords};
             
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: solved]

Comment: Great. // Suggestion: As a next step I'd generalize the \draw commands into a set of \newcommand-macros, to reduce errors, make the source more readable and more universal.